# document getelementbyid setting value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

My html:

```
<h1 id="test">15</h1>
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("awesome");
    document.getElementById("test").value = 10;
}, 2000);
```

After 2 seconds, `awesome` gets logged, but 15 doesn't change with 10 on DOM. any idea?

Comment: use `.textContent`, `.value` is for inputs

Comment: it's happened cause you to use `H1` element. you instant change to form elements like input text or others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the value of `h1` tag, it is needed to use `innerHTML`, instead of `value` because `h1` has no `value` attribute.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("awesome");
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 10;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<h1 id="test">15</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This Could Be also 1 Solution
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("awesome");
    document.getElementById("test").textContent = 10;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more correct to use `innerText` in this task

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("awesome");
    document.getElementById("test").innerText = 10;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<h1 id="test">15</h1>
```